# make bootable iso with only assembler

Tags: assembly, boot, iso

For floppy disk, I can make a boot.img file with assembler only.

At the end of source file, I just wrote:

```
org 0x7c00
jmp start
start:
cli
hlt
times 510 - ($- $$) db 0
db 0x55 
db 0xaa
times 1474560 - ($-$$) db 0
```

But now, how can I make bootable iso like above?

in floppy case,

```
times 1474560 -($-$$) db 0
```

was the key.

Comment: whats your exact problem ?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: What do you need the bootloader for? `cli; hlt` would just stop the CPU forever. The `times` instruction fills the rest with zeroes, so there's not much useful functionality here. (The default bootloader i.e. windows writes to a floppy at least shows an error indicating that it is not bootable).

Comment: I want to boot from cd. for that, I need to make iso file. but I feel uncomfortable if I depend on utilities. so I want to make by my hand. that's why I asked 'how to make iso with assembler only'

Comment: this is simplified code. I want to make small game which requires no operating system.

Comment: it's test code to see if I can boot from cd. if it is bootable, the screen will be black. if it is not bootable, no operating system error will occurs

Comment: CD's aren't that simple. CD's can have many different types of bootloaders for different archs. They are encoded (somewhere?) in the ISO9660 fs. See the `-b` option of `genisoimage`. http://linux.die.net/man/1/genisoimage

Comment: Also, see here: http://wiki.osdev.org/Bootable_CD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [MenuetOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MenuetOS)  for an example of a realtime self-supporting operating system all written in assembly.  It all fits on 1.44 MB media.  If you don't *have* to write your own, you could modify that to your purposes.

The official website is http://www.menuetos.net/ and it looks like the OS is actively maintained.

Answer (score 0):

Under Linux you can use `mkisofs` to create an ISO image. That tool has many options, some of which can be used to specify a file used to boot.

```
mkisofs --help
```

CDs and DVDs support several different types of boot loaders depending on the target system and the format used on the media.

With VirtualBox you can test your ISOs without having to burn a physical disk so you can quickly debug your work.